# PHP cURL works with session id, but it doesn't work with cookiejar

Tags: php, session, curl, cookies

I've been trying to get some page data from this website using cURL. Page is behind authorization, using cookies, without SSL.
I checked a lot of manuals and examples of setting up php cURL script, but none seemed to be working.

Every time I run my script, cookie file updates, but I get empty string as a result. If I set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to 1, I get login page as a result. So I assume, original script returns redirect back to login page.
I tried messing with CURLOPT_USERAGENT, CURLOPT_REFERER, but it didn't help.

Also, if I manually set CURLOPT_COOKIE, PHPSESSID (from real login session using browser and human input), it works fine.

So, here's my code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(10);
define('USERNAME', 'username');
define('PASSWORD', 'password');
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');
define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');
define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 'http://website/auth');
define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 'http://website/distribution/index');
$postValues = array(
    'login_msisdn' => USERNAME,
    'password' => PASSWORD
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_FORM_URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath(COOKIE_FILE));
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "PHPSESSID=relkdrgg94gfdgfg834g");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);

$curl = curl_init()
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath(COOKIE_FILE));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are only saving the cookie (using `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`) from your first curl call, but not loading during your second curl call. That's why no cookie is used during second call. Use the following with your second curl call.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath(COOKIE_FILE));
```

Secondly, you have to close your curl hand and initialize it again before making second curl request. The curl option `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` helps to save cookie on file, but it does it when the curl handle is closed.

```
curl_close($curl);
$curl = curl_init();
// here goes the second one
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);
```

Also, as suggested from the comment (that I've missed), enable the option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` so that the curl returns output.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Another note, please use full path for the cookie file. Otherwise it may not work when you run from browser (also make sure you have write permission on cookie file).

```
define('COOKIE_FILE', '/some/directory/cookie.txt');
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, I fixed my code, but it now returns 1, instead of a page.  
If a add curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); to the second call, it returns auth page.

Comment: To clarify, this changed nothing in the outcome.

Comment: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is not set in the second invoke

Comment: Added & fixed my post, but it still returns blank page.

Comment: @Maksim.T Please use fullpath for the cookie file. I have updated my answer too. `define('COOKIE_FILE', '/some/directory/cookie.txt');`

Comment: I tried using fullpath and realpath, same result. It writes cookies into file fine each time I run script in both scenarios.  
The problem is something else.  
I am starting to think this website has some sort of protection.

Answer (score 0):

For save and use cookie file with CURL, i use this code:

```
$ckfile = tempnam('/tmp', 'CURLCOOKIE');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
    1) Make first request in main page and after do the login
    2) I added some headers
    3) Check if are all parameters in post ( ex: "&login=Submit" )
    4) If is basic authorization use curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    5) Debug header/ errors ...
*/

$url1 = "http://website/";
$url2 = "http://website/auth";
$url3 = "http://website/distribution/index";

$user = "username";
$pass = "password";

$post = "user=".$user."&pass=".$pass;


get_url($url1,'',$url1);

$login = get_url($url2,$post,$url1);

$data = get_url($url3,'',$url1);

print_r($data);



function get_url($url,$post,$refer) {
    $ssl = substr(strtolower($url),0,8)=='https://' ? true : false;
    $cookie = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookie.txt';
    $header[0] = "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: ";
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36";
    $refer = !empty($refer) ? $refer : "http://www.google.com/";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    if( !empty($post) ) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    if( $ssl ) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refer);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);

    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    $error = '';
    if( $html === false ) {
        $error = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    }               
    curl_close($curl);
    $arr = array();
    $arr['html'] = $html;
    $arr['info'] = $info;
    $arr['error'] = $error;
    return $arr;    

}
```